# Windows - intercepting binaries before installing

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, binary

How can I intercept moment before installation of any binary on Windows? I would like to stop the process before installation and execute some Python/PowerShell scripts. After that stop the installation process or permit of installing certain binary, it depends on the script's results. Does exist some windows API responsible for that type of operation?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You must write the code to handle your use case, and then show us what you've tried and detail what is not working, so, folks can try and assist. You cannot just pause/stop an installer once started unless that installer provides such a method. What you are asking, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this. You are looking at customer code and lots of experimenting. I really don't get the use case for this effort. If you don't want certain software to run, that is what SRP (Software Restriction Policies) are for. If user need X or Y app, then take it our of the policy blocking.

Comment: AFAIK that would require either a file [system (minifilter) driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/filter-manager-concepts) or [API hooking](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours) of `CreateFile()` calls. Both non-trivial and not suitable for PowerShell. I agree with postanote that it would be helpful if you write more about your use case. Maybe we can find a simpler solution then.